# Azure ML Service Principal Password

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-service-principal

We want to use a service principal in Azure ML to access the Workspace as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-setup-authentication#use-a-service-principal-from-the-sdk), and are wondering how to save the SP password. It says correctly to not store it in the juypter sources, but to use `os.environ['AML_PRINCIPAL_PASS']` instead. But how do I get it into the environment in a way that survives reboot of compute instance etc?

There is a Keyvault in the workspace, but I need to authenticate the SP first before I can access the workspace and thus the keyvault.

Comment: are you trying to authenticate from an Azure ML Compute instance to the Azure ML workspace?

Comment: Yes, exactly as in the examples on the linked page. The main use case is from the Juypter Notebooks in ML to access the Workspace.

Comment: You could set up the Compute Instance with ssh access, and then run ssh <user@compute> "export AML_PRINCIPAL_PASS=<service principal secret>". to set the secret variable from a value on your local computer. But I agree it's bit of a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: That would contradict my understanding of a unix environment (variable). Is it not bound to the session?